# How do I replace all xA6 in my code

Tags: python, encoding

I obfuscated my python 3.5 code and now I am left with these strange black boxes. I am not able to copy them and "search and replace" with some character. How am I supposed to get rid of them? The code won't run, it keeps raising `"syntaxError: invalid character in identifier"`

[image]

This is very frustrating I have been stuck with this issue for hours.

Comment: Get a better editor?

Comment: I am using notepad ++

Comment: If your code is in a file called `script.py`, use a python interpreter to read the contents of the file as bytes: `print(repr(open('/path/to/script.py', 'rb').read()))`. Posting the result will help us understand in an unambiguous fashion what is in the file.

Comment: Why did you obfuscate it and then want to edit it? Just work with the original code.

Comment: @unutbu It's kinda hard to find the exact place the black box appeared https://gyazo.com/46775e7d452daaba452fd1aade2c7751

Comment: @PeterWood Because the script won't run with those black boxes.

Comment: Replace `¦` with whatever it is you want.

Comment: @PeterWood "Can't find any such character" I guess I can't search on the character when it's formatted as hex in the editor.

Answer (score 2):

If you use Notepad++, you can use the HEX-Editor plugin and view the raw hex of your source, and then use Ctrl+H to find and replace "A6" with whatever you desire.

If you do not have that plugin, it's very easy to download it using Notepad++'s built in plugin manager.

The [extended ASCII Tables](http://lwp.interglacial.com/appf_01.htm) tell me that 0xA6 is a broken vertical bar, which certainly doesn't seem like a valid character for an identifier, so no questions there.