# no encoding declared python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keeping getting This error:

`Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xa6' in file Mode.py on line 1369, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`
Because I have ascii text, How do I solve this problem? Thanks

Comment: Did you try following that link? Particularly : https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/#defining-the-encoding

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47381800/1028772